# Previous state in a useState functional component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to rotate an element based on user's input. The thing is that in my functional component I'm using useState hook to store and update the value that user typed but the element gets rotated not based on the last input but on the one before that.

I recreated the simplified example in CodeSandbox to illustrate the issue.

How do I make it work properly in a functional component?

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-clarke-nlyuo?file=/src/App.js:0-762

Comment: Can you store a list/array of all the inputs in state instead of a single number? So OnChange you'd just push the new value into the list, and set the value to display as the old one.

Comment: because setting `style.transform` does not cause React re-render , but the `setValue` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be reaching into the DOM to set the transform. You should remove the querySelector line from your input.

```
<input
  type="number"
  max={359}
  value={value}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    // don't do this 
    document.querySelector("h1").style.transform = `rotate(${value}deg)`;
  }}
/>
```

The state change will trigger a re-render, so just set the transform during render:

```
<h1
  style={{
    transform: `rotate(${value}deg)`,
    border: "1px solid pink",
    display: "inline",
    padding: "10px"
  }}
>
```